# screen recording gstreamer performance issue

Tags: gstreamer

I am building an application where it is essential to record my desktop. I decided to use gstreamer since i m using c++ to develop my application . 
I use ximagesrc to record my dekstop. 
this is how the line in the code looks

```
gst_parse_launch("ximagesrc ! queue ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-rgb,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! theoraenc ! queue ! oggmux ! filesink location=test.ogg",&error);
```

I am able to record the desktop. I am using dual core computer with 2 GB Ram . But the problem i have is , when i play the recorded video , at time it plays and at times, it hangs . I am not able rely on this completely. Is there any solution ? or am I doing anything wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the same question in the forum for gstreamer and i got some good responses. 
One of them mentioned to use "use-damage=0" with ximagesrc. And i reduced the frame rate as well. Its looks like this.

```
gst_parse_launch("ximagesrc use-damage=0 ! queue ! videoscale ! video/x-raw-rgb,width=640,height=480,framerate=10/1 ! queue ! ffmpegcolorspace ! theoraenc ! queue ! oggmux ! filesink location=test.ogg",&error);
```

This worked well and the machine didnt hang after this. The main reason i think its because, when you use use-damage=0, it sends the updates of the screen rather than sending the whole screen. Hence, it reduces the cpu as well and better the performance.

Comment: Usually screencast software don't do live compression. Instead raw data is saved until the recording is over. Only then is the footage compressed.